# Use same date/time format in DRF as for models.DateTimeField

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Build` model with a `start_time` field, which is of type `models.DateTimeField`. On the other hand I have a `BuildSerializer` class that includes this `start_time` field. Now when I print the timestamp in my templates, I get a result like this:

```
{{ build.start_time|format:'DATETIME_FORMAT' }}
```

in my template will become:

```
April 24, 2015, 8:03 a.m.
```

However, the serializer outputs a different value:

```
2015-04-24T08:03:39.336922Z
```

This is fine as it is a standard JSON date representation. However, I’d like to display it in regard to the user’s locale, like Django does when I use the above template snippet does.

I tried to use

```
timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT)
```

but DRF uses a different way to format date outputs, so this will just output:

```
"N j, Y, P"
```

for the default `en-us` locale.

Is there a way to format a date exactly like Django does? I’m interested in both a python or a JavaScript solution, as I process the JSON in a JS function (AJAX callback) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would *highly* recommend keeping your dates formatted as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (that's what the default is) as it is a consistent and standardized date format, so you don't need to worry too much about parsing dates manually anywhere. Most languages can parse ISO 8601 dates, and those that can't by default generally have libraries which can do it for you.

> Is there a way to format a date exactly like Django does?

Django REST framework by default only supports formatting a date-related field using a single formatter, which is ISO 8601 by default. This is for general consistency, so clients can send an `OPTIONS` request and parse the date format directly from there and rely on the date format never changing.

You *can* override this behaviour by either having a property on your model or a `SerializerMethodField` that overrides the return value such that it calls Django's date formatting utilities if you want to localize the value on the backend. Alternatively, you can override the default `DateTimeField`'s `to_native` method and do the formatting there, that way you can have a field that can be used across serializers so the localization is consistent.

> I’m interested in both a python or a JavaScript solution, as I process the JSON in a JS function (AJAX callback) anyway.

The JavaScript solution that we use for parsing ISO 8601 times is [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). While some browsers *can* parse ISO 8601 times, not all can and it is easier to pass them off to Moment so they can be converted in [JavaScript Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
// parse the incoming date/time string
var start = moment(response.start_time, moment.ISO_8601);
```

The first argument to `moment` is the string to be parsed, and the second argument is the format to parse from. `moment.ISO_8601` is a special hook that can automatically parse it as a valid ISO 8601 time, which is why we use it.

From there you can use the browser's Date localization to present the user a localized version of the time. Date objects provide `toLocaleString()`, `toLocaleDateString()` and `toLocaleTimeString()` methods that can be used to format the different parts of the date (or the entire thing) how the user is expecting it.

Testing locally on Chrome (on Ubuntu, en-US) I get the following outputs for the methods

```
> (new Date()).toLocaleString()
< "6/2/2015, 7:23:03 PM"
> (new Date()).toLocaleDateString()
< "6/2/2015"
> (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()
< "7:23:12 PM"
```

Which is how I've configured my date settings for this browser. This has the additional bonus of always using the current time zone for the system, so you don't need to worry about that part of localization - it's handled automatically.

Comment: Great answer with much details, I appreciate that! The root of the problem is that we generate the same listing in two different places: in the HTML template and from a JSON response generated by a DRF serializer. I know this is against the DRY principle and we are currently trying to eliminate it, but with the current methods used it is hard without dropping the site's usability. That's why I came to the solution you can read in my own answer.

Comment: I've come here from the google, you could extend the answer with 2021 update, where we can use toISOString on native Date object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 0):

I have came to a solution pretty fast, although I consider it a bit ugly:

```
from django.utils import formats

class BuildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timestamp_django = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_timestamp_django(self, obj):
       return formats.date_format(obj.timestamp, 'DATETIME_FORMAT')

    class Meta:
        model = Build
        fields = ('timestamp', 'timestamp_django', …)
```

This way I get the best of both worlds, as I can still use the JSON date for other purposes (like filtering or sorting).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, based on [Kevin Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30608247/823321):

```
from django.utils import formats
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

class DateTimeField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    """DateTime field whichs supports Django's format definitions."""

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT in formats.FORMAT_SETTINGS:
            return formats.date_format(obj, api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT)
        return super().to_representation(obj)


class DateField(serializers.DateField):
    """Date field whichs supports Django's format definitions."""

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if api_settings.DATE_FORMAT in formats.FORMAT_SETTINGS:
            return formats.date_format(obj, api_settings.DATE_FORMAT)
        return super().to_representation(obj)


class TimeField(serializers.TimeField):
    """Time field whichs supports Django's format definitions."""

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if api_settings.TIME_FORMAT in formats.FORMAT_SETTINGS:
            return formats.date_format(obj, api_settings.TIME_FORMAT)
        return super().to_representation(obj)
```